# Dismiss UIImagePickerController when Enter Background modes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I use UIImagePickerController for using Camera and Camera Roll in my project.

This is my example code

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

It worked but if i want to dismiss it when i enter to background mode.
how to fix it.

Thank you and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can listen to the [UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html) notification using the [NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

With that, you can setup a method to be called whenever the app goes into the background where you can check if the picker is being displayed (perhaps store a reference to it whenever it is being displayed):

```
- (void)presentImagePicker
{
    if (self.displayedPicker) {
        return;
    }

    self.displayedPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.displayedPicker.delegate = self;
    self.displayedPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self presentViewController:self.displayedPicker animated:YES completion:nil];

    // Register for the method to be called every time the app enters the background
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
        addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(didEnterBackgroundNotification:)
        name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
        object:nil
    ];
}

- (void)dismissImagePickerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (self.displayedPicker) {
        [self.displayedPicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:animated];
        self.displayedPicker = nil;

        // Unregister from notification
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
            removeObserver:self
            name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
            object:nil
        ];
    }
}

- (void)didEnterBackgroundNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [self dismissImagePickerAnimated:NO];
}
```

Comment: I'm new in ios Developer. Can you help and recomment about NSNotificationCenter for me? How to use it.

Comment: I STRONGLY recommend that you look at the documentation and try to google for it because those are essential skills to truly learn a new development paradigm / environment, but I also updated my answer above to show how you can register for the method to be called whenever the notification is posted.

Comment: Thank you now I can resolved my problem but it has some bug. I try to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the `UIImagePickerController` a property in your class. In your AppDelegate Class you can implement the applicationDidEnterBackground: Method in wich you can put something like this:

```
[yourViewController.picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

This should dismiss the ImagePicker if your app enters the background. Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: I don't recommend trying to implement this from the app delegate. The app delegate probably doesn't have a clean way of letting the view controller know that it should dismiss the picker and this type of task is outside the responsibilities that the app delegate should have. Using the UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification is a cleaner way for a view controller to know about entering the background.